# Dynamically Generate Test Fixtures and Test Cases in NUnit using folder structures and XML Files

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, nunit, integration-testing

I am trying to generate tests dynamically based on the structure of folders that contain XML files. (The tests use the XML files to drive Selenium RC)

So say for example I have 3 Folders which also contain sub folders (each of which contain the Data.xml file I use to drive selenium RC)

```
TestData
    TestFixtureOne
        TestCaseOne
        Data.xml
        TestCaseTwo
        Data.xml
        TestCaseThree
        Data.xml    
    TestFixtureTwo
        TestCaseOne
        Data.xml
        TestCaseTwo
        Data.xml
    TestFixtureThree
        TestCaseOne
        Data.xml
        TestCaseTwo
            Data.xml
        TestCaseThree   
        Data.xml
        TestCaseFour
        Data.xml
        TestCaseFive
        Data.xml
```

The code I currently have is like so

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using NUnit.Framework;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;
namespace NUnitIntegration
{
    [TestFixture]
    class SeleniumTest
    {
        private static string testDirectory;

        public SeleniumTest()
        {
            testDirectory = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TestDirectory"]; // Let’s assume this value is “C:\TestData\”

        }

        [SetUp]
        public void init()
        {
            // Nothing needed as of yet
        }

        [Test, TestCaseSource("GetTestCases")]
        public void TestSource(string test)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Successfully executed test for: " + test);
        }

        [TearDown]
        public void dispose()
        {
            // Nothing needed as of yet
        }

        private static string[] GetTestCases()
        {
            return getTests();
        }

        private static string[] getTests()
        {
            return Directory.GetDirectories(testDirectory);
        }
    }
}
```

But this will only bring me back the TestFixtureOne, TestFixtureTwo, and TestFixtureThree folders (see below) which is not what I am after. I was trying to make it flexible so that I can added more tests if needed (more TestFixtures and TestCases).

[NUnit Test Tree]
TestSource
    TestFixtureOne
    TestFixtureTwo
    TestFixtureThree

I have searched quite relentlessly recently and came across these threads which helped me very much, but now I am stuck!

[used in multiple [TestFixture]s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3557904/test-used-in-multiple-testfixtures)
(And another thread where I got the above code from)

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Regards

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether you need to use the GetFiles() method to get the XML files, but to get the directories recursively you could use

```
return Directory.GetDirectories(testDirectory, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

More information on this function [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53zya234.aspx).